# Pass get values to method and call in jsp page

Tags: spring, forms, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm using spring mvc, making a small web-app.
I have a form in a jsp page, and I'm trying to pass the values from my .GET controller to a method and display the results from the called method after pressing the "Submit" button on the same JSP page or another, preferrably on the same page.

This is how the form looks like:
http://i65.tinypic.com/6gyo02.png

This is the method I want to be called after getting the values from the form:

```
public void calcMacros() {
        int goal = 0;
        if (this.goal == 0.7){
            goal = 1;
        } else if (this.goal == 0.9) {
            goal = 2;
        } else if (this.goal == 1) {
            goal = 3;
        } else if (this.goal == 1.2){
            goal = 4;
        }

        switch (goal) {
            case 1: weightLoss();
                    weightLossProtCalc();
                    weightLossCarbCalc();
                    weightLossFatCalc();
                break;
            case 2: weightLoss();
                    weightLossProtCalc();
                    weightLossCarbCalc();
                    weightLossFatCalc();
                break;
            case 3: tdeeCalculator();
                    maintainProteinCalc();
                    maintainCarbCalc();
                    maintainFatCalc();
                break;
            case 4: weightGain();
                    weightGainProtCalc();
                    weightGainCarbCalc();
                    weightGainFatCalc();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        System.out.println("selected goal was " + goal + "and proper methods have been called.");
    }
```

Best question would be, how can I transform this method into a .POST controller so I can display it's results in the same JSP page. Also how do I call this method/controller in the JSP page?

Thank you!

Edit: Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/calculator" ,  method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String calculatorPage(ModelMap model, MacroCalculatorForm macroCalculatorForm) {
        model.addAttribute("user",getPrincipal());
        macroCalculatorForm.calcMacros();
return "calculator";
    }
```

Would this do it, or should I rewrite the method I want to get called into this controller?

Comment: Where is your GET controller ? Add the code here

Comment: @javaguy I added the controller, should I rewrite the controller with that method within it?

Answer (score 0):

You should have two methods in your `@Controller`:

(1) One method which supports `GET` : This is to provide the display `View` of the first page (before the calculations).

(2) One method which supports `POST`: This is to process the inputs received from the first page and then sending the results to the View (JSP) back.

Answer (score 0):

Reading values from **GET** requests is easy. It's only need to define parameters with input names as  following for age example :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/calculator" ,  method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String calculatorPage(ModelMap model, 
         MacroCalculatorForm macroCalculatorForm,
         @RequestParam(value = "age") int age)
    {
        //Now you can use age value in your method 

        model.addAttribute("user",getPrincipal());
        macroCalculatorForm.calcMacros();
        return "calculator";
    }
```